# Combine multiple PDF files into one (arranged in a matrix)

Tags: pdf, images, imagemagick, plotting

Having a set of PDF files, lets say: `in-01.pdf`, `in-02.pdf`, `in-03.pdf`, ... I would like to combine all of them into a single one, forming an `M x N` matrix.

The command `montage` allows for doing so (`M` and `N` should be integers):

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile NxM in-*.pdf out.pdf
```

The problem is the size of the resulting PDF is huge, while I would expect it to be (maybe just) a little bigger than the sum of all the input PDF sizes. I think `montage` is first converting the input PDFs to images and then creating the output PDF out of those images (so for example, the text in the original PDFs is not showed as text in the output PDF, but as an image with lower quality and bigger size).

I guess there should be a way to do it (LATEX, for example, allows to insert a PDF image in another PDF without the need to convert it to an image first).

I am looking for a command line alternative using free software tools under GNU/Linux systems.

**NOTE**: we can asume those PDF files have all the same exact dimension (width and height). They are auto-generated PDF images normally consisting of a plot/graph (simple shapes line lines and rectangles) and a few text (title, labels...).

Comment: You are correct about what `montage` does :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the utility program `pdfnup` from the [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) suite.

```
pdfnup in.pdf --nup 3x3
```

should output the file *in-nup.pdf* with the pages of *in.pdf* arranged in a series of pages with a 3x3 matrix from the origin pdf.

You should merge all of you pdf files in an only one, also you must want to specify a paper size for the output file, see the pdfjam docs fot the details.

Comment: In case you have a prefix in all input files (i.e. `in-`), then you may want to use `pdfnup in-*.pdf --nup 3x3 --outfile out.pdf` to avoid having an output file with the same prefix. Also, notice how you don't really need to merge all input files into one (you can simply use the `*` wildcard). You may want to add that to your answer.

Comment: Thanks! it works. Saved me so much time.

Comment: Sounds like the `pdfnup` wrapper script has been removed from the main `pdfjam` package after v. 3.02. See [pdfjam-extras](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam-extras). If you look at the wrapper script, you can see it does just a one line command for pdfjam. You should try `pdfjam --suffix nup --nup 2x1 --landscape input.pdf` to produce `input-nup.pdf` which is a 2-up layout of `input.pdf`. Likewise you could do `pdfjam --suffix nup --nup 2x2 input.pdf` to make a 4-up layout etc.

Answer (score 1):

The layout you are trying to emulate here is called [N-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-up). There are a few ways of doing this. As in xae's comment, you can do this with pdfjam. See my comment there. For example:

```
pdfjam --suffix nup --nup 2x2 input.pdf
```

will produce a 4-up, 2x2 matrix. Alternatively you can pass the `--landscape` option to orient the matrix as viewed from landscape instead of portrait.

You could also do this going through postscript

```
pdf2ps input.pdf input.ps
psnup -4 input.ps output.ps
ps2pdf output.ps output.pdf
```

where `-4` means 4-up (2x2)

And if you are directly trying to print this pdf file on linux, I think the CUPS client includes a version of the Berkley LPR print spooler (`lpr`) with an N-up option. You can use the option with

```
lpr -o number-up=4 input.pdf
```

or set it as default

```
lpoptions -p QueueName -o number-up=4
```